# Is this kind of notation legal in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 61.2180556, longitude: -149.9002778};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
```

What is this? Curly brackets?

Also shouldn't that be CLLocationCoordinate2D * coord

I saw them on http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/39374-mkmapview-tutorial-using-latitude-longitude.html

Totally strange.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, forget my old comment, those are C structs and I think that's valid syntax for initializing structs.

Comment: why the downvote? seems like a reasonable enough question to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is C99 “designated initializer” syntax for initializing structs. (It has nothing to do with the Objective-C concept of “designated initializers” for classes.)

Comment: I just realized I was wrong: this is the obsolete GCC “fieldname” extension. The equivalent C99 designated initializer syntax, which you should use instead, looks like this: `CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { .latitude = 61.2180556, .longitude = -149.9002778 };` You can also use it in arrays: `int foo[5] = { [3] = 2 };`. If you use these forms, uninitialized fields are zeroed out.

Comment: This does not answer whether or not this is legal Objective-C. Are C99 constructs part of Objective-C?

Comment: Unlike C++, Objective-C is defined in terms of and layered on top of standard C. If you compile Objective-C code with the compiler set to accept C99, all C99 constructs are accepted.

Comment: Ah, that explains the "C Language Dialect" I see in the build settings.